# Metcalfe's law for bitcoin price

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, address, value, prediction

Here's an inline link to [article](http://markets.businessinsider.com/currencies/news/bitcoin-price-movement-explained-by-one-equation-fundstrat-tom-lee-metcalf-law-network-effect-2017-10-1007560818)

article

  the square function number of users times the average transaction value. 94% of the bitcoin moved over the past four years is explained by that equation.

It does't make sense for me about a mathematical equation of 94% explained bitcoin price in this article.

If I'd like to predict a bitcoin price of following day using this equation, is this as following?

square function number of users × the average transaction value

↓
　　square number of unique addresses per day × 
(trade volume(USD) per day / number of transactions per day)

↓

604,054^2 × (597,502,689 / 271,995) = 801,644,073,110,452

date: 2017/11/14 00:00

Here's an inline link to [reference unique addresses
(https://blockchain.info/charts/n-unique-addresses?timespan=30days)

Here's an inline link to [reference trade volume]
(https://blockchain.info/ja/charts/trade-volume?timespan=30days)

Here's an inline link to [reference transactions]
(https://blockchain.info/ja/charts/n-transactions?timespan=30days)

Answer is very huge number.
Could someone explain that concretely where the wrong is?

Thank you